# Какое событие применить в jQuery

Tags: jquery, события

Хочу при вставке ссылки в текстовое поле, вызвать отдельный метод. Событие change не подходит, потому как после вставки ссылки требуется сделать клик извне блока. А нужно налету.

Answer (score 8):

Делал подобный функционал для автоматического получения информации о видео при вставке ссылки на YouTube и другие видео хостинги, навешывал сразу несколько событий:

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtLink').bind('input paste change', function() {
        $('#lblDisplay').text($(this).val())
    })
});
```

Демо:

- Демонстрация кода: http://jsfiddle.net/uxYxH/
- Пример с получением информации с YouTube + Vimeo: http://jsfiddle.net/ugjAP/5/

Comment: Можете поделиться скриптом?

Comment: Сейчас поищу, этот кусок по памяти дал.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Есть такой же парсер ссылки с добавлением картинки для VIMEO и VK.COM ?

Comment: там надо поставить setTimeout(function(){},0); т.к. данные в поле появляются **после** отработки события.

Comment: @Chetson: С Vimeo проблем нет, так как он поддерживает OEmbed. (пример добавил). Youtube также имеет поддержку OEmbed, и грамотнее запрашивать информацию через него. С VK не все так просто, насколько я помню там информацию можно получить только авторизованному пользователю.

Comment: @eicto: спасибо, готово

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keydown(function() {

//code

});
```

либо

```
$('input').keyup(function() {

//code

}
```

Разница понятна из названия

---

```
$('input').bind('paste', function (e) {

    alert(1);

});
```

Comment: @Undefitied, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: оба случая не сработают на вставку мышью.

Comment: для вставки мышью обновил
});

Comment: paste  поддерживается только в IE. :) для остальных - input. зачем ваш ответ вообще, если есть ответ от Павла ?

Answer (score 0):

Это легко реализуется с MVC-фреймворком на подобие [Ангуляра](http://angularjs.org/).

Пример от RubaXa: [jsfiddle.net/du3b2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/du3b2/1/)

Comment: :] Простите, но у вас mvc/ангуляр головного мозга. Внутри себя, ангуляр использует тот же jQuery (jQLite) и точно также подписывается на события "input". Ну и правильный пример для Angular будет таким — http://jsfiddle.net/du3b2/1/

Comment: Даж не знаю что ответить. Вроде бы и оскорбили, но и ничего дельного не сообщили.

Comment: Простите, не хотел обидеть, просто ваше решение, это как из "пушки по воробьям". + Ваш пример не показывал, как отловить момент изменения инпута.

Comment: Да, согласен, нужно было уточнить.